VolumeMountFailure when .net aspire with postgres deployed to azure
I have a .net aspire project with an postgres db. As long as I'm working locally it seems to work fine. But when I deploy to Azure with azd up the postgres container does not come up and stays on pending. When I check the console stream I see this error:
{"TimeStamp":"2024-09-18 11:44:05 \u002B0000 UTC","Type":"Warning","ContainerAppName":"postgres","RevisionName":"postgres--ok3j4qt","ReplicaName":"postgres--ok3j4qt-75547cdff4-rw5gb","Msg":"Container \u0027postgres\u0027 was terminated with exit code \u0027\u0027 and reason \u0027VolumeMountFailure\u0027. One or more errors occurred. (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(2): No such file or directory\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)\n) (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(2): No such file or directory\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)\n)","Reason":"ContainerTerminated","EventSource":"ContainerAppController","Count":7}

I setup everything in the AppHost with this:
var postgresPassword = builder.AddParameter("postgresql-password", secret: true);
var db = builder.AddPostgres("postgres", password: postgresPassword)
    .WithDataVolume()
    .WithPgWeb()
    .AddDatabase("db");

The setup is based on this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/database/postgresql-integration?tabs=dotnet-cli.
The naming of the password is according of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/persist-data-volumes
When I replace Postgres with SQL server it also seems to correctly mount the volume and the container comes up.
I see that in the message it says Reason: No such file or directory. But I can see that the storage account and a file share are created in the azure portal and it looks pretty much identically to what the setup did create for an SQL DB in terms of volumes and shares.
Is this a bug in the postgres package or does this require some more setup steps?
